# Using variable named '@subject' in Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

In one of my mailer methods I used a variable title '@subject'. By default, I was expecting this to be present in the corresponding view. However, after wasting quite some time looking around, I realized that the problem was in the variable name. Changing it to anything but @subject worked. Is there a place where these keywords are defined, I google around but didn't find any such listing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @Wahaj first of all @subject is not keyword!, you can use reflection  to get information about class before using it.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#Ruby

You can get all instance method by `object_or_class.instance_methods` message or just call `object.methods` will return available methods, there is lots more google it

Now when you call action mailer method like

```
 UserMailer.welcome(params)
```

it return  `Mail::Message`   object https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L143

here is result of Mail::Message reflection

```
 m=Mail::Message.new => #<Mail::Message:-634435678, Multipart: false, Headers: > 
 m.methods => [....,"subject", "subject=",...]
```

it seems that `subject` is `attr_accessor` in `Mail::Message` class but it is not, subject getter and setter are setting subject value in a header hash..

```
#a part from Mail:Message class 
#  mail.subject "G'Day mate"
#  mail.subject #=> "G'Day mate"
def subject( val = nil )
  default :subject, val
end

# Sets the Subject value of the mail object, pass in a string of the field
#
# Example:
#
#  mail.subject = '=?UTF-8?Q?This_is_=E3=81=82_string?='
#  mail.subject #=> "This is あ string"
def subject=( val )
  header[:subject] = val
end
```

Comment: There is typo in your answer.. It should be UserMailer.welcome(params) not UserMailer.welocme(params)

Comment: Moreover still it is unclear why @subject does not work as it is not a keyword

Comment: @ShirjeelAlam so you have down vote answer because it has typo?  moreover still subject is not keyword!! and its not feasible to have a list of instance variable,and method for all classes if you have access to source code and also have power of reflection,use it man hopefully you got it!!

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a canonical site so far but Paul Sturgess has a couple of articles about reserved words [here](http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/81-ruby-on-rails-activerecorddangerousattributeerror) and [here](http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/30-wrong-argument-type-string-expected-module-ruby-on-rails-error). Err The Blog has a [list](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rails_reserved_words/) but I did not see "subject" listed (also this list is repeated on a few different sites so Err may not be the original author).